# For each entry in a sub array add values

Tags: javascript, arrays, mern

```
let b = [];
this.state.sidejobs.forEach((user) => {
  console.log(user);
  if (!b.hasOwnProperty(user.jobworker)) b[user.jobworker] = 0;

  b[user.jobworker] += user.duration;
});
```

One entry in jobworker has an array with two ids... how do i split it and add the duration respectively.

```
Name          ID        Total Hours
Mike Smith    281           5
            284,281         5
John Doe      284           21
Chris Smith   283           23
```

Comment: what kind of result do you want?

Comment: Can you eloborate on your question further by providing some sample inputs and expected result?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, is b an array or an object? Or are you using it as both? I suspect you meant for it to be an anonymous object.

```
let b = {};
```

Secondly, it would really help to know the exact structure of user.jobworker (eg: call "JSON.stringify(user.jobworker)"). For now, I will assume that the structure of the user object is as follows:

```
{
 name: "Mike Smith",
 id: 281,
 duration: 5,
 jobworker: [284, 281]
}
```

If that is the case, all you have to do is

```
let b = {};
this.state.sidejobs.forEach((user) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < user.jobworker.length; i++) {
    if (!b.hasOwnProperty(user.jobworker[i])) b[user.jobworker[i]] = 0;
    b[user.jobworker[i]] += user.duration;
  }
});
```

If instead user.jobworker contains a comma-delimited string of ids (eg: user.jobworker = "284,281") then you will have to split the string first:

```
this.state.sidejobs.forEach((user) => {
  var jobworkers = user.jobworker.split(",");
  for (var i = 0; i < jobworkers.length; i++) {
    var worker = jobworkers[i].trim();
    if (!b.hasOwnProperty(worker)) b[worker] = 0;
    b[worker] += user.duration;
  }
});
```

Comment: TypeError: user.jobworker.split is not a function
render/<
C:/exercisetracker/mern-exercise-tracker/src/components/sjcalloutlist.component.js:51

  48 | 
  49 |    let b = [];
  50 |    this.state.sidejobs.forEach((user) => {
> 51 |      var jobworkers = user.jobworker.split(",");
     | ^  52 |      for (var i = 0; i < jobworkers.length; i++) {
  53 |        var worker = jobworkers[i].trim();
  54 |        if (!b.hasOwnProperty(worker)) b[worker] = 0;

Comment: Sidejobs is an array and jobworker is another array with strings in each entry

Comment: let b = [];
    this.state.sidejobs.forEach((user) => {
      var jobworkers = user.jobworker.toString().split(",");
      for (var i = 0; i < jobworkers.length; i++) {
        var worker = jobworkers[i].trim();
        if (!b.hasOwnProperty(worker)) b[worker] = 0;
        b[worker] += user.duration;
      }
    });

Answer (score 0):

```
   let b = [];
    this.state.sidejobs.forEach((user) => {
      var jobworkers = user.jobworker.toString().split(",");
      for (var i = 0; i < jobworkers.length; i++) {
        var worker = jobworkers[i].trim();
        if (!b.hasOwnProperty(worker)) b[worker] = 0;
        b[worker] += user.duration;
      }
    });
```